# Encoding issue of a character in utf-8

Tags: python, utf-8, beautifulsoup, python-requests, mojibake

I get a link from a web page by using beautiful soup library through `a.get('href')`. In the link there is a strange character `®` but when I get it became `Â®`. How can I encode it properly? I have already added at the beginning of the page `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

```
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
```

Comment: Not enough information to answer your question. How to tell that it "became" "Â®"? Maybe it's just our output that is wrong?

Comment: I got in the terminal that character when I print the string

Comment: How did you load the page into BeautifulSoup? It was decoded as Latin1 instead of UTF-8 somewhere. The PEP263 comment applies *only* to your source code, not to any other data you loaded.

Comment: I use the requests object. I'm updating the code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do *not* use `r.text`; leave decoding to `BeautifulSoup`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
```

[`r.content`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.content) gives you the response in bytes, without decoding. [`r.text`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.text) on the other hand, is the response decoded to `unicode`.

What happens is that the server did not include the character-set in the response headers. At that moment, `requests` follows the [HTTP RFC 2261, section 3.7.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.7.1): `text/` responses *by default* are expected to use the ISO-8859-1 (Latin 1) character set.

For your HTML page, that default is wrong, and you got incorrect results; `r.text` decoded the bytes as Latin-1, resulting in a [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake):

```
>>> print u'®'.encode('utf8').decode('latin1')
Â®
```

HTML can itself include the correct encoding *in the HTML page itself*, in the form of a [`<meta>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) in the HTML header. BeautifulSoup will use that header and decode the bytes for you.

Even if the `<meta>` header tag is missing, BeautifulSoup includes other methods to [auto-detect encodings](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#encodings).